# What means the comparison between empty parantheses without a function and content of curly brackets

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a code right now and in this code are some parts which I not understand. Especially the setInterval part in which are empty parentheses and comparing with the comparing operator =>  with the content of the curly braces. Further if the querySelector is better than defining an id and access the html elements with getElementById. Lastly I want to know if the onclick method which is not in HTML part but in the javascript part is a implemented method of javascript

```js
const s = document.querySelector('span');
const b = document.querySelector('button');

let interval = null;
b.onclick = () => {
  // Start the interval
  if (!interval) {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      s.innerText = parseInt(s.innerText) - 1;
    }, 1000);

    b.innerText = "Pause";
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;

    b.innerText = "Resume";
  }
}
```

```html
<span>100</span>
<button>start</button>
```

Comment: 1. `function()` without parameter; `() =>` arrow function without parameter

Comment: 2. giving an element an id and use getElementById is better than querySelector

Comment: 3. It is recommended to use `addEventListener` instead of `on`